# Java Regex: capture group between two characters and then match character within captured group

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regexp-replace

**Question:** How can I first capture a group(s) between two characters, and second match a character within that matched group(s)?

**Given Input:**

```
atribute="value1" AND atrribute="*value2"
```

**Problem 1:**
I want to capture a group between two characters, unlimited number of times.

Regex solution:

```
(?<==|!=|>|>=|<|<=|IN|NOT IN).*?(?=AND|OR|$)
```

Captured groups:

```
"value1"
"*value2"
```

**Problem 2:**
I want to match a character within the captured group(s)

Attempted regex solution 1:

```
(\*)(?<==|!=|>|>=|<|<=|IN|NOT IN).*?(?=AND|OR|$)
```

Attempted regex solution 2:

```
[*](?<==|!=|>|>=|<|<=|IN|NOT IN).*?(?=AND|OR|$)
```

**My issue:** neither of the above attempted solutions capture the **asterisks** in the input string. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can place the capture group after the lookbehind, and then optionally match `"` followed by capturing the asterix

```
(?<==|!=|>|>=|<|<=|IN|NOT IN)(?:\"(\*))?.*?(?=AND|OR|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lyHNpS/1)